# How to attach an image to an object?

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface, object

I am a beginner Java programmer, working on a very simple game. I have learned the basics of OOP and am trying to test & expand my knowledge.

In my game, there is a projectile object. The game takes place inside a JFrame.

How would I display the projectile object visually inside the JFrame? I would like to use an image/picture. I essentially want to 'attach' an image to the projectile object.

**Main Class**

```
public class MathGame implements ActionListener {

    private static JButton[] choices = new JButton[4];
    private static JLabel[] options = new JLabel[4];
    private static double[] nums = new double[4];
    public static JPanel container;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Math Game");
        frame.setSize(300, 500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // container
        container = new JPanel();
        container.setLayout(null);
        frame.setContentPane(container);

        // title
        JLabel title = new JLabel("Math Game");
        title.setBounds(113, 10, 80, 15);

        // option labels
        for (int i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
            options[i] = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
            options[i].setBounds(5 + (72 * i), 50, 68, 68);
            nums[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
            options[i].setText(Double.toString(nums[i]));
            options[i].setOpaque(true);
            options[i].setBackground(Color.RED);
        }

        // buttons
        for (int i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
            choices[i] = new JButton();
            choices[i].setBounds(5 + (72 * i), 420, 68, 20);
            choices[i].addActionListener(new MathGame());
            container.add(choices[i]);
        }

        // progress bar
        JProgressBar progress = new JProgressBar();
        progress.setBounds(5, 450, 284, 20);
        progress.setValue(0);
        progress.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        progress.setStringPainted(true);

        // adding it all
        for (int i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
            container.add(choices[i]);
            container.add(options[i]);
        }
        container.add(title);
        container.add(progress);

        // extras
        frame.toFront();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Projectile bullet = new Projectile(150, 250);
        System.out.println(bullet.toString());
    }
}
```

**Projectile Class**

```
public class Projectile extends Piece {

    public Projectile(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y);
    }

    public void fire() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            this.yPos = this.yPos - 5;
        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2)
            throws IOException {

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\jbakos\\Desktop\\pew.png"));
        g2.drawImage(image, this.xPos, this.yPos, null);

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't read the image in the drawing code.  Read your images while you're constructing the GUI.  Reading an image from your disk is like 1,000 times slower than drawing the image on your drawing JPanel.

Answer (score 1):

First, add a JPanel to JFrame. JFrame is a root container and is not recommended to take up elements like JButtons, JLabels, etc., so you need a sub-container for that

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
frame.add(panel);
```

Set the LayoutManager of panel to null, that allows you to position child elements absolutely inside the panel

```
panel.setLayout(null);
```

Now, add a JLabel with an ImageIcon which will carry the picture to the panel and position it via setBounds

```
JLabel lbl = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(picture));
lbl.setBounds(x,y,width,height)
```

I am not sure what your game application is going to look like, but I advise you to use null layout on the game content area only and use other layout managers for the remaining parts.

Answer (score 0):

New java programmer myself.

And it depends, I am doing something similar. I made a JPanel that displays a grid, so it displays a 'piece' or object on each square of an 8x8 grid. And then you could display the JPanel within that JFrame

To display an image, the draw method() is similar to below.

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g2, int x, int y)
            throws IOException {

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("location of image"));
        g2.drawImage(image, x, y, null);


    }
```

Refer to this for more specifics:
[How do I draw an image to a JPanel or JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865465/how-do-i-draw-an-image-to-a-jpanel-or-jframe)

Comment: I saw your edit. Essentially, with the code above will do the same considering your enemy object is its own class with a paint method. Once you create an enemy object, the method above will draw it on that location, where that image will 'represent' the enemy object.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, if you could comment on this, I could try to expand my answer.

Comment: Okay. I'm added all the code, however, it does not paint an image upon creation.

Comment: Could I see your enemy object and your JFrame code?

Comment: Add it to your main post. Ctrl-K to highlight the code as a code

Comment: Okay, added the 2 relevant classes.

Comment: @jzbakos under `Projectile bullet = new Projectile(150, 250);`, try doing `frame.add(bullet)`

Comment: Could you upload your piece class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129169/discussion-between-jzbakos-and-bao-thai).