# How to set JPanel background?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have an issue with JPanels. I have two layers of JPanel. The first layer is JPanel with image and second layer show JComponents. It looks like this:

```
JFrame
 - JPanel1 (Image)
    - JPanel2 (JComponents)
```

When I have more than one component on `JPanel2`, then `JPanel2` is not transparent but it has a grey background and I don't see `JPanel1(image)` under it. How to set `JPanel2` as glass pane when his parent is `JPanel1`?

Comment: https://ctrlv.cz/9uet here is picture. Grey background of JPanel2 cover JPanel1

Comment: Don't overlap one panel with another. Simply draw image on the panel which holds components. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865465/how-do-i-draw-an-image-to-a-jpanel-or-jframe) is an example.

Comment: Alternative: do not use an image for that. You can achieve the same effect with regular Swing components

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, don't use transparency for something like this. Check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for the problems you will encounter. However for full transparency you just use `panel2.setOpaque(false)`.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy This solution is not good for me beacause i dont use Override methods with paintComponent a have mine method where i drawImage and show components and this method call everywhere i need repaint. When i use only one JPanel then Image cover my components or components cover image with grey background too.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Swing doesn't support alpha based background colors, doing so well lead to additional painting artifacts and the practice should be avoided

Comment: @Tomm23 Have you tried making the panel transparent?  `setOpaque`?

Comment: @camickr ahh okay. seems like i confused contentpane and jpanel, because content pane doesn't support `setOpaque`. thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, i did. i setOpaque to panel2, but now panel2 is real transparent. But now a see color of background of panel1 because aj try set background color to yellow of panel1.

Comment: [picture](https://ctrlv.cz/GVww) with code:jPanel2.setBackground(Color.white);
        jPanel2.setOpaque(false);
        jPanel1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        jPanel1.setOpaque(true);

Comment: @Tomm23, Not sure what the point of your last comment is for. Your image doesn't display. Images should be loaded to this forum, not an external website. All Swing components (except JLabel) are opaque by default. So you only need to use panel2.setOpaque( false ). Setting the background of panel2 will do nothing because the entire panel is now transparent. If you code doesn't work then post an [mcve] demonstrating the problem.