# Image is not showing when Java program is running

Tags: java, image, frame

Whenever I run the program, the background image is not visible, it is just a white blank space. I tried following the instructions on this website -> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-add-background-image-to-jframe-in-java, but is not working. I tried the getImage method and provided the file path towards that image. Can someone please explain what is wrong with my code and how to fix it?

```
public class MainForm extends JFrame {
    
    Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\Jack\\Desktop\\Folder\\Course\\Draft repo");
    public MainForm() throws IOException {
      this.setContentPane(new JPanel() {
         @Override
         public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
         }
      });
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
   }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new MainForm();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
    });
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `.jpg` forgotten? And better, more modern style is to use `ImageIO` for reading.

Comment: i want to insert a borderlayout to add the two frames on top of the background image, is that possible?

Comment: Add a separate JPanel for your background at the CENTER, leaving the default content pane as it is. Adding to the JFrame is the sane as adding  to the content pane. Then add other panels to SOUTH, NORTH or whatever.

Comment: I tried to add add(img, BorderLayout.CENTER); but I kept getting this error "no suitable method found for add(Image, string)". Netbeans' suggested fix was to add "Create method "add(Lyrics.java.lang.String) in MainForm". The fix isn't really that necessary and might ruin the codes

Comment: No, you should add a new JPanel with its paintComponent just as it is done now. Alternatively you can use a JLabel and set its icon with an image.

Comment: *to add the two frames on top of the background image* - what two frames? An application consists of a single JFrame. You can then add components to the frame. Typically you add a JPanel which contains other Swing components. Use proper terminology when asking a question so we don't have to guess what you are really asking.

Answer (score 0):

according to: [How do I draw an image to a JPanel or JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865465/how-do-i-draw-an-image-to-a-jpanel-or-jframe) ,
instead of using

```
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Path\\image.jpg");
```

try to use:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Path\\image.jpg"));
```

Do not forget to indicate the correct path to the file and the file itself with the extension.